# Circles in a circular shape i.e 6 circles in a circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, bootstrap-4

Here I have tried to show the buttons in a circular shape using bootstrap, CSS, and HTML5. I want it in exact circular shape. Friends, can you please fix it. Please try to help me I want it in responsive too. Below is my code kindly go through it. Here I have tried to show the buttons in a circular shape using bootstrap, CSS, and HTML5.

```
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="row" align="center">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="">Product
              identification</i></button>
        </div>



<div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="">Cataloguing, listing <br> and pricing</i></button>
    </div>

    </div>

   </div>  

   <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="row" align="center">

      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="">Cataloguing, listing <br> and pricing</i></button>
      </div>

      </div>

     </div> 

   <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="row" align="center">

      <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="">Front ending <br> end customers</i></button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="" style="font-size:17px;"><b>ZRPL</b></i></button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="">Enhance product <br> visibility and deals</i></button>
      </div>

      </div>

     </div> 

     <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="row" align="center">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="">Returns and ARB management</i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="">Logistical
              support</i></button>
        </div>

        </div>

       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css style in your button. It will make a circular shape on you button. you can give any `width` and `height` value on your button. just make sure that height and width should have same value.

```
width:170px;
height:170px;
border-radius:50%
```

Comment: Bro, thats not the issue here..i want that circular buttons to be arranged in circular form..